# AspNetCore - Serilog - Incorrectly logging to IISExpress folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

As you can see from the two screenshots, i have two services in the same solution but in different projects with identical config setup for both but for some reason logging to two different locations.

[image: Logs to IISExpress Folder]
[image: Relative Logging]

**AppSettings.json**

```
 {   
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Debug"
        }
        },
        "AllowedHosts": "*",
        "Serilog": {
          "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug"
          },
          "WriteTo": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "./logs/.log",
                "rollingInterval": "Day"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
}
```

Just want to log to a relative logs folder and that's it.

Lastly, any improvements i can make, then let me know.

Comment: That certainly looks like the same issue ... I never even knew about this InProcess hosting model.

Comment: Some useful reading for anyone who lands:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2